# UIButton State (UIControlState)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

How do I set the state of of UIButton ?

In the UIButton class reference there is a "state" but it is only "readonly".

Thanks
James

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set `selected` property for example

```
buttton.selected = YES;
```

Also `enabled` and `highlighted` properties are available.

Note that all these properties set a bit mask on control's state which you can get using read-only `state` property.

Answer (score 4):

```
myButton.highlighted = YES/NO;
myButton.selected = YES/NO;
myButton.enabled = YES/NO;
```

These are defined on `UIButton's` ancestor `UIControl`.

Answer (score -1):

The above 2 replies are quite the answers.

It is to be noted that you cannot change `state` of a `UIButton` directly. The state is changed indirectly by other event triggers.